# No arbitrage iff there EMM $P^*$ theorem

Tags: probability-theory, finance, martingales

The definition of an arbitrage I was given:

"An arbitrage strategy is an admissible strategy with zero initial value and positive probability of a positive final value."

I think that an initial value of zero was not really necessary for an arbitrage, as long as all the values are non-negative and we have a strictly positive cash flow at sometime ( which could very well be the initial time). In fact I have seen examples in my exercises where this is the case!

Now I just finished learning the proof of the theorem stating that there is no arbitrage iff there is an equivalent martingale measure $P^*$ and in the proof we in fact make use of the fact that the initial value is zero.. So we in fact absolutely need this fact. So how come I have seen exercises where we are supposed to use NA arguments when the strategy does not have a zero initial value?

Comment: You seem to expect the Reader to have a copy of the same textbook and exercises that you have in quantitative finance.  I think you may well know examples of arbitrage practice where the initial value is positive, but this does not exclude the use of that strategy when the initial value is zero.  So there is no contradiction apparent here.  It isn't exactly clear what question is being posed.

Comment: An arbitrage is defined to have zero initial value. But in exercises ( a lot of them!) we construct arbitrage strategies to create a contradiction and conclude some fact. The thing is that in many exercises the constructed "arbitrage strategy" needs to have a non zero initial value. And then this is not an arbitrage according to this definition. Further in the proof we are strictly proving something about  an arbitrage with zero initial value.

Comment: So what are we contradicting in these exercises? This theorem would not apply to our "arbitrage strategies" because they are not arbitrage strategies in the sense of the theorem

Comment: ie when we are assuming NA we are really assuming the existence of EMM... and this is equivalent to no arbitrage with zero initial value..

Comment: Does that clarify my question?

Comment: I don't understand the question, but that is more a personal limitation.  You cannot contradict a definition (there may not be anything that satisfies the definition, but the definition is still an abbreviation for a certain combination of conditions).  The theorem you refer to (in some unspecified text) is probably using "arbitrage" in the precisely defined sense given in the same text.  At the same time you have seen in the coursework examples of "arbitrage" as a trading strategy that may or may not involve having positive assets to work with.  I'm guessing you see a contraction in this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's quite common to distinguish between Type A arbitrage and Type B arbitrage. We say that a trading strategy is a

- **type A arbitrage** if it has a positive initial cashflow and no risk of future loss.
- **type B arbitrage** if it has a nonnegative initial cashflow, no risk of future loss and a positive probability of future profit.

I think what you are referring to is a type A arbitrage. Obviously, definitions may vary.

Comment: But then the theorem only applies to type B arbitrage? In the proof of the theorem we use that $V_0=0$... A possible resolution would be to show that for any type $A$ arbitrage there is an "equivalent" in some sense arbitrage strategy of type $B$... Do you understand what I mean?

Comment: Well, straight from the definitions above, a type A arbitrage is also a type B arbitrage. In fact, if we have a strategy giving a positive initial cashflow, see that we could alter the strategy slightly, by investing the amount obtained at time 0 in the risk-free asset. This will give $V_0 = 0$, and it is a type B arbitrage. I'm not exactly sure if this is what you are looking for, since I haven't seen the proof.

Comment: sounds good to me nice point thank you